# How do I make PyCharm/PyDev/other IDEs offer code completion for IronPython namespaces?

Tags: python, namespaces, ironpython, pydev, pycharm

I like PyCharm and have used it before for my Python projects, but I just started messing with IronPython and I can't figure out how to make PyCharm or any other IDE for that matter (except for VS which works fine) recognize the .NET libraries.

For example, I have the code:

```
from System.Environment import *

path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

The above code works fine, but the "System" part is underlined grey everywhere with the message "Unresolved reference System". The IronPython documentation explains that System is not a module but rather a namespace. If I do `type(system)` I get `<type 'namespace#'>`. So is there a way to make PyCharm/PyDev recognize the namespaces as well? On a side note, the PATH is fine, everything is fine.

Answer (score 5):

For performance reasons, PyCharm does not generate Python stubs for .NET assemblies by default. You can trigger the generation by putting the caret on an unresolved reference in an import statement, pressing Alt-Enter and selecting the "Generate stubs for binary module ..." quickfix.

Comment: Thanks, but clicking on it doesn't do anything (the menu disappears and nothing happens). Nothing happens in the "Background Tasks" either. Also, none of the options from the Generate stubs submenu do anything either.

Comment: It's a bit of a hit & miss with "Generate Stubs". Sometimes it will work, sometimes it will just churn and churn and eventually fail.

Answer (score 3):

Just to note, this should work properly in PyDev (just make sure that you configure an IronPython interpreter and configure your project as an IronPython project).

Another note is that the code above should actually be:

```
from System import Environment

path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not PyCharm but Michael Foord has info on how to do this w/ Wing: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/wing-how-to.shtml - PyCharm may have some similar mechanism available.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately the script he provided didn't work for me, and I don't think that PyCharm has this option either.